# Cannot find GooglePicker mimeTypes for doc and docx

Tags: reactjs, web, google-picker

Im using **react-google-picker** for my react app to open google drive and i want to open only specific doc types(doc, docx, txt) in file picker.

Documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker) provide file types for images but not for others.

```
mimeTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']}
```

I found the file type for text is as

```
mimeTypes={['text/doc']}
```

Could anyone please help me to find exact file types for **doc** and **docx**

Following is the way i load picker component

```
<GooglePicker clientId={'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'}
                  developerKey={'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
                  scope={['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']}
                  onChange={data => this.uploadDriveFile(data)}
                  onAuthenticate={token => this.setGoogleDriveToken(token)}
                  onAuthFailed={data => console.log('on auth failed:', data)}
                  multiselect={false}
                  navHidden={false}
                  authImmediate={false}
                  mimeTypes={["text/doc"]}
                  query={''}
                  viewId={'DOCS'}>
      <button> open google drive </button>
    </GooglePicker>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the file types for doc and docx also

```
mimeTypes={["text/plain", "application/vnd.google-apps.document", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/msword"]}
```

where

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.document", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

both belongs to docx
and

```
application/msword
```

belongs to doc